# Bot Framework Card for showing all the contacts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

Currently we are showing top 3 contacts using Adaptive Card
Now we need to add extra button to show all the contacts
Please can anyone help which card to be used to show all the contacts details on button click.

Comment: No it didn't resolve

Comment: Can provide with a example, need something like a card with actions
I have tried adaptive card with show card(showing the details of contacts on clicking the card) but it is coming up in iterative manner multiple cards

Comment: Not sure if I get your question but in Adaptive cards you have Action.ToggleVisibility. With templating you should be able to put all other contacts in a container that becomes visiblle after the button with the Action.ToggleVisibility is pressed.